# How to use thead class in android

Tags: android, multithreading

im working on the project to turn on LED using Android application and will communicate with Wi-Fi.

The problem is the application is always crash when I push the button to send the instruction into remote device (I'm using Arduino + wifi shield). I think the problem is my construction of thread and the execution. Can anyone solve my problem, how to use thread class properly in android?

Here is my code for the thread class

```
package com.gfhz.appliancecontrol;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionSocket extends Thread {

    Socket client;
    ConnectionInfoActivity conInfo;
    String instructionCode;
    String serverAddr;
    OutputStream os;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    String stoast;

    final int port = 2000;

    ConnectionSocket(String instruction) {
        // Get the DEVICE ID
        String devId = conInfo.getDevId();
        // Concatenate instruction message and device Id
        instructionCode = devId.concat(instruction);

        // Get the SERVER IP ADDRESS
        serverAddr = "192.168.1.105";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);          
        try{
            // Open a socket
            client = new Socket(serverAddr, port);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(instructionCode);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            stoast = "Unknown Host Exception" + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated cach block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Display in TOAST
            stoast = "IO Exception" + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getTContext(), stoast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

And here the code to execute the thread

```
package com.gfhz.appliancecontrol;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LightsMenuActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights_menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_lights_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void powerLamp1 (View view) {
        Thread cs = new ConnectionSocket("0401");
        cs.start();
    }
    public void powerLamp2(View view) {
        Thread cs = new ConnectionSocket("0402");
        cs.start();
    }
    public void powerLamp3(View view){
        Thread cs = new ConnectionSocket("0403");
        cs.start();
    }
}
```

The logcat error:

```
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     ... 11 more
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at com.gfhz.appliancecontrol.ConnectionSocket.<init>(ConnectionSocket.java:25)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     at com.gfhz.appliancecontrol.LightsMenuActivity.powerLamp1(LightsMenuActivity.java:37)
11-16 19:49:21.127: E/AndroidRuntime(7457):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Pls show the logcat crash info.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I've added the error logcat sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat shows there is a NullPointerException at line 25 of your ConnectionSocket class.

That is why the app is crashing.

---

In addition to that, I recommend you look into Android specific background threading implementations, like AsyncTask for example.

They are much easier to work with than the raw Thread class.